# "из-за" vs. "ради"

Tags: выбор-слова

I would mostly use `из-за`, but actually I do not know the difference, nor when to go for `ради`.

Could anybody give me a hint, please.

For instance in

> Ты здесь из-за меня?
>   Ты здесь ради меня?

Are both variants possible?

Comment: Hi @embert, it would help if you could provide some context. The two words are different, and it is difficult to judge from your question, what is actually unclear.

Comment: In your example both versions are possible in the meaning 'in order to meet me or to be near me', but the second one expresses it more clearly. The version with "из-за" is slightly indirect and more like 'did you come just because I'm here?'

Answer (score 11):

***Из-за*** (due to some condition, limitation, for the reason of) usually explains the reason for something what happened, or is about a possible consequence in nearest future as a reason for taking some preventive measure. *Из-за кого-то* sometimes means someone is to blame or is the reason for something unpleasant.

> Из-за автомобильных пробок он опоздал.
>
> Из-за прогнозируемого падения курса рубля он перенес свою поездку на более ранний срок.

***Ради*** — for getting a desired result, sometimes 'for the sake of'.

> Он согласился на эту командировку только ради того, чтобы увидеть Китай.
>
> Ради своей девушки он был готов на многое.

So the main difference is **'for the reason'** vs. **'for a result'**.

Answer (score 2):

And do not forget `благодаря` , which can also be a tricky synonym of `из-за` sometimes:

> **Из-за** автомобильных пробок он опоздал.
>
> **Благодаря** автомобильным пробкам он не попал в аварию.

[The difference between “благодаря” and “из-за”](http://learnrussian.rt.com/grammar-tables/difference-between-blagodarya-and-iz-za/)

Answer (score 2):

"Из-за" is normally used as "because of" and in the sense of laying a blame. To ask "Ты здесь из-за меня?" is to mean "Is it my fault that you're here?"

"Ради" is normally used as "for" and in the sense of providing assistance. To say "Ты здесь ради меня?" is synonymous to "Are you here for me?"